# aws elasticache with php - unable to set key/value pair

Tags: php, memcached, aws-sdk, amazon-elasticache

I am able to connect to my elasticache cluster like so:

```
$awsElasticache = new ElastiCacheClient(CredentialProvider::atsDefaultConfigConstructor(false, false));
$clusterResult = $awsElasticache->describeCacheClusters(array('CacheClusterId'=>'my_cluster'));
```

When I print `$clusterResult`, I get info about the cluster, good.

But how can I actually interact with the endpoint to set key/value pairs?

I am trying this without success:

```
$this->mem = new Memcached();
$this->mem->addServer($this->endPoint,11211);
$this->mem->set('myKey','myValue',3600);
$result = $this->mem->get('myKey');
echo $result;
```

I get nothing printed from `$result`.
I am confused about which object to use to set and get key/value pairs.

Comment: Are you referring to Memcached? From the class you used, seems its memcache you were referring too

Comment: how do you figure that, when I'm attempting to use memcached? hence Memcached(). Should I use Memcache instead?

Comment: Yes, use Memcached for quick value storage and retrieval. But it should never be used to substitute a database. From your current question, seems Memcached would fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

To set key/value pair in Memcached, always extend the time of expiry from current time.

Try this

```
$this->mem = new Memcached();
$this->mem->addServer($this->endPoint,11211);

$expires = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
$this->mem->set('myKey','myValue', $expires);
$result = $this->mem->get('myKey');
echo $result;
```

`NOTE:` For some reason, Memcached works best with `Carbon` time

See https://artisansweb.net/work-php-datetime-using-carbon/ on how to setup and use `Carbon` on your current project